# Is "the loop" a template tag?

Tags: loop, templates

Template tag is defined the following here:

> Template tags are used within themes to retrieve content from your
>   database.

**The loop** retrieves (posts) content from database in templates, so it seems she would fall in that category. Hence I ask:

Is "the loop", the loopish function that shows posts while we have posts, based on if we have posts, should actually be considered a a template tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Template tag` is just a name chosen for a variety of function. It doesn't really matter what you call them, and they are functions.

However, the `while( )` loop itself is a simple PHP feature. It uses the `have_posts` method of the `WP_Query()` class to detect whether there is any posts to display or not. The main query itself is already set when you load a page, which can be accessed via `global $wp_query;`.

So, putting all together, this can be an opinion based question. The `WP_Query()` class doesn't exists in the [File](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Files) section of [Template Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) page, so I would call it a *"No"*.